# ActiveModelSerializer: how to add association to custom attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have a serializer with custom attribute and I need to include an association to that custom attribute, but cannot figure it out:

```
def dependent_integrations
  object.integrations.includes(:service_integrations).where(service_integrations: { master: false}).map do |integration|
    # this.integration.organization_integrations ===> I need to include organization_integrations into to integration object for serializer
  end
end
```

And get this JSON for the code:

```
"dependent_integrations": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Confluence Cloud",
                    "key": "confluence-cloud",
                    "description": "blablaabla",
                    "vendor": "Atlassian",
                    "active": true,
                    "created_at": "2020-04-08T18:16:01.000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-04-08T18:16:03.000Z",
                    "custom": false
                },
            ]
        },
```

But I need to get the following JSON with organization_integrations included:

```
"dependent_integrations": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Confluence Cloud",
                    "key": "confluence-cloud",
                    "description": "blablaabla",
                    "vendor": "Atlassian",
                    "active": true,
                    "created_at": "2020-04-08T18:16:01.000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-04-08T18:16:03.000Z",
                    "custom": false,
                    "organization_integrations": [
                        {
                           id: 1,
                           .......
                        },
                        {
                           id: 2,
                           .......
                        }
                    ]
                },
            .........
            ]
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `include` option in the render method.

```
def your_action
  # ...
  render(
    :json,
    include: 'parent_model.integrations.service_integrations',
    # ...
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to the is render an association inside your serializer.
What you need to do is to work with different serializers for each model you're rendering. Note that you didn't specify what version of rails you're using so the following code may not work properly

```
# your serializer
def dependent_integrations
  ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(integrations, each_serializer: IntegrationSerializer).as_json
end

private

def integrations
  object.integrations.includes(:service_integrations).where(service_integrations: { master: false })
end

# IntegrationSerializer
class IntegrationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :key, :description, :vendor, :created_at, :updated_at, :custom, :organization_integrations

  def organization_integrations
    ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(object.organization_integrations, each_serializer: OrganizationIntegrationSerializer).as_json
  end
end

# OrganizationIntegrationSerializer
class OrganizationIntegrationSerializer
  attributes :id # ...
end
```